# Simple Option Menu (C)

Tags: c

I am trying to make a simple option menu that is executed within a do- while loop. The menu has 5 different options. I am currently trying to test the the get initial option but when I choose the case 'b' the function does not even execute and the option menu reappears again

```
#include "mathprogram.h"


int main (void)
{
    char menu_option,initials;
    int difficulty;

    printf("        EDUCATIONAL MATH PROGRAM!!!\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n\n");


    do{
    printf("Main Menu\n");
    printf("a. Learn about how to use program.\n");
    printf("b. Enter your initials (3 individual letters).\n");
    printf("c. Difficulty Selection.\n");
    printf("d. Start a new sequence of problems.\n");
    printf("e. Save and quit.\n");
    printf(" Please enter an option from the main menu: ");
    scanf("%c",&menu_option);



    switch(menu_option){

    case 'a':
        //Learn_to_use();

        break;
    case 'b':
        initials=get_intials();

        break;
    case'c':
        printf("case c");
        //difficulty = get_difficulty();
        break;
    case'd':
        break;
    case'e':
        break;
    default:
        printf("invalid input");
            break;
    }

    }while(menu_option !='e');







    }
```

get initials function:

```
#include "mathprogram.h"

char get_intials(void){
    char initails;
    printf("Please Enter Initials: ");
    scanf("%c",&initails);
    return initails;

}
```

Comment: Works for me. When I enter `c` it prints out `case c`. It does print the menu twice, once for 'c' and once for '\n'.

Comment: yeah i noticed that too, i dont want it to print twice. but my main concern was why my case b wouldnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%c", &var);
```

leaves the newline in the buffer or stream.

Try to change it to

```
scanf(" %c", &var);
```

and it should work as expected (Note the space before the **%**; this consumes the whitespace so that the next scanf call should work).

However, the initials as defined in your program consist of only one character, not three. I'll leave that up to you to design, that is a different question.

Comment: Thanks this helped the menu not repeat more than once. About that three character string i know that i will have to do something with arrays in my char variable

Answer (score 1):

There's a '\n' between option 'b' and the initials char, the "scanf" must handle it.
Complete code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char get_intials(void){
    char initails;
    printf("Please Enter Initials: ");
    scanf("\n%c",&initails) ;
    return initails;
}

int main (void)
{
    char menu_option,initials;
    int difficulty;

    printf("        EDUCATIONAL MATH PROGRAM!!!\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n\n");


    do{
    printf("Main Menu\n");
    printf("a. Learn about how to use program.\n");
    printf("b. Enter your initials (3 individual letters).\n");
    printf("c. Difficulty Selection.\n");
    printf("d. Start a new sequence of problems.\n");
    printf("e. Save and quit.\n");
    printf(" Please enter an option from the main menu: ");
    scanf("%c",&menu_option);

    switch(menu_option){

    case 'a':
        //Learn_to_use();

        break;
    case 'b':
        initials=get_intials();
        printf( "input initials:%c\n", initials) ;
        break;
    case'c':
        printf("case c");
        //difficulty = get_difficulty();
        break;
    case'd':
        break;
    case'e':
        break;
    default:
        printf("invalid input");
            break;
    }

    }while(menu_option !='e');
}
```

output:

```
Please enter an option from the main menu: b
Please Enter Initials: c
input initials:c
```

Comment: This didnt really help pressing b in the menus options still doesnt let me execute the get_initials() function. It would show the printf("Please enter initials: "); and then return to menu without me inputting initials.

Comment: Ok, I think maybe there's some environment difference. I changed a little and pasted complete code. Please check.

Comment: The thing is i want my initials to have three characters i enter in "TMI". and aslo the menu prints twice

Comment: But "char" and "%c" only take one character. Do you want to input "TMI" one time or separately?

Comment: yes i understand that now but do u know why my menu prints twice after the intial is entered

Comment: because your menu is in the do..while loop, and while menu_option !='e', it runs from "printf("Main Menu\n");" again... Maybe you want the first line in do{ } is "scanf("%c",&menu_option);" ....

Comment: is there a way i can resolve that. i need the menu to show again if the user does not want to quit

Comment: do you mean you want get_intials() executed three times? then you can put it into a while loop , such as:  char initials[3]; int i = 0; while( i < 3 ){  initials[i]=get_intials(); i++; }

Comment: no the whole point of my get initials function was to save a three letter string and store it into char initials;. But my main concern has to do with getting my menu to not print more than once after a case has been executed

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
This code includes a stray \n from previous input due to which get_initials method was not working properly,it picked up the remanant \n in the input stream and concluded,
flushing the input stream is the solution to the problem, uncomment the code at line 8 to get proper functionality
*/
#include <stdio.h>
char get_intials(void){
    char initails;
    //fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please Enter Initials: ");
    scanf("%c",&initails);
    return initails;

}

int main (void)
{
    char menu_option,initials;
    int difficulty;

    printf("        EDUCATIONAL MATH PROGRAM!!!\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n\n");


    do{
    printf("Main Menu\n");
    printf("a. Learn about how to use program.\n");
    printf("b. Enter your initials (3 individual letters).\n");
    printf("c. Difficulty Selection.\n");
    printf("d. Start a new sequence of problems.\n");
    printf("e. Save and quit.\n");
    printf(" Please enter an option from the main menu: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&menu_option);



    switch(menu_option){

    case 'a':
        //Learn_to_use();

        break;
    case 'b':
        initials=get_intials();
        if(initials == '\n')
            printf("\n%s\n","I was there in stream as newline");
        //printf("\n%c",initials);
        break;
    case'c':
        printf("case c");
        //difficulty = get_difficulty();
        break;
    case'd':
        break;
    case'e':
        break;
    default:
        printf("invalid input");
            break;
    }

    }while(menu_option !='e');






return 0;
    }
```